# How to search for post title, content and post meta in WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a search criteria where I need to search for either post_title, post_content or post_meta called 'description'. while saving the post:

```
  $post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_status'   => 'publish', 
            'post_type' => "courses"  
            );
  $id = wp_insert_post($post);
  update_post_meta($id, 'description', $description);
```

While searching for the post I am using the below code:

```
  if($_GET['tewa_search'] != ''){

        $keyword = $_GET['tewa_search'];
        $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'courses',
        array('s'=> $keyword),
        'meta_query' => array (
            'relation' => 'OR',
                array (
                  'key' => 'inistitute_name',
                  'value' => array ($institute_name),
                  'compare' => 'IN'
                ),
                array (
                  'key' => 'description',
                  'value' => $keyword,
                  'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            ),
        'posts_per_page' => '5',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft'),
        'order' => 'DESC'
        )); 

    }
```

Presently only post title is working fine but if I search for post_meta "description" then its not working. can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this link : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99849/search-that-will-look-in-custom-field-post-title-and-post-content

Comment: @hardik solanki, that's not clear bro.. In that question only one meta_key they were using but here 2 meta_key's I am using that is 'inistitute_name' & 'description' along with 'post_title'